# How to Unset iTunes Track Start And Stop Time For Multiple Tracks?

Tags: itunes, applescript

For some reason a lot of tracks in my iTunes library have senseless start and stop times set. This is really annoying as some tracks get skipped after a few seconds. There are Apple Script commands for setting them but I didn't find a way to clear all times. How can I batch clear them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this script from dougs scripts on latest iTunes and it worked on the few tracks I selected.

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=resettracksstartstop